# Azure pipelines self hosted agent - should there be separate users for building and deploying?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We want to use azure pipelines to deploy application on on-premise virtual machines. We are trying to see if we should use self hosted agents in azure so that we can try to manage access to private network. The tech stack is Microsoft based so we will install visual studio enterprise (for build and code coverage).

What are the best practices in setting up the self hosted agent?

- Should there be a specific build user which is linked to visual studio license on the server?
- Should there be a specific deploy user that has access on the on premise servers to copy artifacts like IIS websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Should there be a specific build user which is linked to visual studio license on the server?

No, you can check that here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Visual-Studio-Licensing-Whitepaper-Mar-2020.pdf

> Using Visual Studio on the Build Server

> If you have one or more
> licensed users of Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription, Visual Studio
> Professional Subscription, or any Visual Studio cloud subscription
> then you may also install the Visual Studio software as part of Azure
> DevOps Server 2019 Build Services. This way, you do not need to
> purchase a Visual Studio license to cover the running of Visual Studio
> on the build server for each person whose actions initiate a build.

2. Should there be a specific deploy user that has access on the on
   premise servers to copy artifacts like IIS websites?

Basically, yes. This user has to have corresponding permissions on target servers. However, you can use tasks that define users like [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) and [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops).